# Getting back the old BottomBar

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

Just started a new app and when including a `BottomNavigationView` the result look like that : [image]

I really don't get where it come from and how can I get back to the old version that are still defined in the [spec](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-specs)

Does someone know where these changes come from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default BottomNavigationView add shiftingmode = true when its more than 3 items. so try this

```
static void removeShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
    try {
        Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
        shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
        shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
        shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
            item.setShiftingMode(false);
            // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
            item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        Log.e("ERROR ", "Unable to get shift mode field"+e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "Unable to change value of shift mode"+e);
    }
}


BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
BottomNavigationViewHelper.removeShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't know about this. Thanks !  (will accept the answer)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create **helper class** for this :

```
public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {
    public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
        }
    }
}
```

**In activity :**

```
 BottomNavigationView bnav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomnav);
 BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bnav);
```