# how to make bottomnavigationview items like imagebutton

Tags: android, webview, android-support-library, bottomnavigationview, androiddesignsupport

I am working on a webview app,  I want a bottombar like opera, uc browser. When I use bottomnavigationview, and add a menu.

my bottomnavigation view

[image: my bottomnavigation view]

like above. It takes the first element as clicked and uses shift mode.

I searched a lot after that I got this: https://montemagno.com/remove-shifting-bottomnavigationview-android/

they disable shift mode, but I just want items to behave like imagebuttons. back to the same state after a click.

How to do that??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44673656/getting-back-the-old-bottombar/44673753#44673753

Comment: Try this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44342585/8089770 In this there is code of shift mode as well. try and let me know if any error

Comment: Thanks...I am going to check this. But now I found that bottomnavigationview should not use for simple tasks in material guidelines. What to do ?

Comment: can not resolve setShiftingMode(false) error. What to do?